# Advantages of popup over panels in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, popup, windows-phone-7.1

I'm curious about `Popup` control in Windows Phone. For me, it's some kind of panel, that has `IsOpen` property. And I should used it, when i want to present some only in some defined context (e.g. button pressed).

But why not use just normal stack, or grid panel, and when use `Visiblity` when you want to hide, or show it?  It's seems to behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Horizontal and Vertical position of the popup using the HorizontalOffset /VerticalOffset properties in the Popup control. We don't have that option in the Grid and to other panels.

Answer (score 0):

It is an overlay. It doesn't break page layout as it shows above the main content.
While `StackPanel` or `Grid` should be added to main content and when they are shown they'll move other controls down.